# How do you create a Direct Line token app on Azure

Tags: azure, dialogflow-es, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

Need to create token from Direct Line Speech secret

To date I have been able to migrate a dialog flow chatbot into Azure - however I want to display the chatbot in a browser with a speech-text-speech feature: similar to this demo on Github here: https://microsoft.github.io/BotFramework-WebChat/06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js/

However I cannot create the app to convert the Direct Line Speech secret into a token.

Example from Github:

```
const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
const { token } = await res.json();
```